# Covert rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my sql query

```
With Months(monthNumber) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT month_number + 1 FROM [AndriodAppDB].dbo.T WHERE month_number < 12)
(
SELECT
 monthNumber, SUM(T0.Debit-T0.Credit) [Balance Due]
from 
Months
CROSS JOIN dbo.JDT1 T0
INNER JOIN dbo.OCRD T1 ON T0.shortname = T1.cardcode and T1.cardtype = 'c'
where  T1.CardCode ='C-SGD-0242' and T0.RefDate <= EOMONTH('2022',monthNumber-1)
group by monthNumber
)
```

This is my results

```
monthNumber Balance Due
----------- ------------
1           18176.570000
2           17110.380000
3           18832.900000
4           18832.900000
5           18832.900000
6           18832.900000
7           18832.900000
8           18832.900000
9           18832.900000
10          18832.900000
11          18832.900000
12          18832.900000
```

But i need output like this:

```
Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug     Sep       Oct Nov Dec 
18176.57 17110.38 18832.90 18832.90 18832.90 18832.90 18832.90 18832.90 18832.90 18832.90 18832.90 18832.90
```

Comment: You need pivoting, look that up.

Comment: yeah but how to achieve with my current query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

use *DateName(M, DateAdd(M, monthNumber, -1))* to change your number to its name (12 =>[December]) then use pivot as follows

```
---make your query to YOURCTE(with) is your table in use it in pivot
---with

select *
from 
(
 SELECT DateName(M, DateAdd(M, monthNumber, -1)) month1,BalanceDue from YourCTE
) src
pivot
(
  sum(BalanceDue)
  for month1 in ([January], [February], [March],[April],[May],[June],[July],
  [August],[September],[October],[November],[December])
) piv;
```

or more complicated

```
select *
from 
(
 SELECT DateName(M, DateAdd(M, monthNumber, -1)) month1,BalanceDue from ( SELECT
 monthNumber, SUM(T0.Debit-T0.Credit) [Balance Due]
from 
Months
CROSS JOIN dbo.JDT1 T0
INNER JOIN dbo.OCRD T1 ON T0.shortname = T1.cardcode and T1.cardtype = 'c'
where  T1.CardCode ='C-SGD-0242' and T0.RefDate <= EOMONTH('2022',monthNumber-1)
group by monthNumber
) yourquerytable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(BalanceDue)
  for month1 in ([January], [February], [March],[April],[May],[June],[July],
  [August],[September],[October],[November],[December])
) piv;
```

Comment: Can possible to edit my query With. Currently when i run it throwing some error

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.

Comment: This filter is important "T0.RefDate <= EOMONTH('2022',monthNumber-1)" otherwise the data will be wrong

Comment: yes, i used that in order get the correct result

Comment: create month table (1,2,3,4,5,)  in your database and use second query

Comment: Did it worked??

Comment: wow i am impressed

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean way to do that in a generic way. T-SQL assumes that you know all of the column names at compile time, which is something that it can't know if the column names come from the data.

If you do know all of the column names ahead of time, you can use the `PIVOT` clause.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: But i am using an With Statement along with cross join